Configure Ubuntu in a bootable external SSD as a persistent boot option
Some time ago I created a bootable external SSD with Ubuntu 22.04 on it, following what's highlighted in How to create a truly portable (plug-n-play) Ubuntu installation on an external SSD/HDD.
Up until now I basically used it every day without unplugging it much. Now, since I believe I'll do it more often, I'd like to have it more convenient.
Before, it booted automatically since I set it as first in the boot order. At the moment, instead, every time I unplug it, it clearly disappears from the boot menu. The downside is that every time I do want to use it and I plug it back in, it is not the first choice, so I have to manually enter the boot menu and choose it.
Is there a way to set things up such that, if the SSD with Ubuntu is present, it is always the first option for booting?
EDIT: as requested by @user68186: in my internal drive I only have Windows, no grub in the EFI. grub only comes with the external drive (the bootable SSD with Ubuntu)

Depends upon the firmware.  You used to be able to select "USB" as first in the boot order, but now, that really doesn't control the acutal order, there might be another "hard disk" ordering which contains the boot item you want, and it may list only when the "hard disk" is present. However, this second ordering is likely to be the same one as you get from the EFI boot menu (some key at power-up) to allow you to choose the boot device/OS, so just use that to boot the grub on the USB (assuming you set up the external boot with a valid grub boot -- EFI partition, and grub install.

Nice reminder about the USB ordering, I'll have to double check the firmware!
I'm not sure about the other thing you say though: I don't seem to be able to access the grub directly, if the drive was unplugged before... am I missing something?

@user68186 info added! I'll repeat here too: no grub in EFI, only Windows there

The GRUB configuration file is opened with a text editor:
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

The line GRUB_DEFAULT=
Option 0 causes the first entry  in your menu to be selected by default.
Option 1 causes the second entry  in your menu to be selected.
And so on.
If the option is saved,  the last entry accessed is always selected.
Whenever this file is modified, GRUB must be updated for it to take effect:
sudo update-grub

--- Edited ---
The GRUB that needs to be modified is the one from Ubuntu installed on the internal disk.
--- End of edition ---

Will this work if grub is not installed in the internal drive's ESP? If the last boot was external and the external drive is unplugged on the next boot, will grub gracefully boot from the internal drive?

I might be mistaken, but isn't this for the boot menu of the SSD itself? as @user68186 said, this is OK once my laptop "boots into" what's in the SSD, but what about before that?
like, right now if the external drive was unplugged before I have to go: laptop boot menu ("BIOS") -> choose external drive -> grub boot menu -> Ubuntu. I think this gets rid of the second selection menu only, right?

@kyodake what if I don't have a grub on the internal disk? can I install it there, without installing a whole Ubuntu system?

Yes, Ubuntu is installed on the SDD and it is marked that Ubuntu is installed on the internal HD or SDD, with an option for the other operating system(s) installed on it.
